# Proper way to close dialogs in Flutter tests

Tags: testing, flutter

Flutter's WidgetTester has a `pageBack()` method for popping the route stack. When I open a page as a fullscreen dialog using MaterialPageRoute's `fullscreenDialog` property, the `pageBack()` method does not work ("One back button expected on screen"). I can't find an alternative method for the job.

What is the standard way to cancel/close a dialog in a Flutter test?

I am able to close the dialog as follows:

```dart
await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.close));
```

But then I could have instead done a `pageBack()` as follows:

```dart
await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.arrow_back));
```

Why have the `pageBack()` method but no equivalent for closing a dialog?

I have not yet written my Cupertino UI yet. Will that test need to look for a different icon?

See also a similar [problem I had with selecting the overflow menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58464657/tapping-the-overflow-menu-in-a-flutter-test).

UPDATE: Maybe `pageBack()` emulates pressing the system back button, not the back arrow? In that case, there would be no need to emulate the behavior on iOS, and I would have to find the back button by icon to emulate pressing it, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dialog that contains a button with a text 'X', which pops the dialog.
This button, you can find with

```
await tester.tap(find.text('X'));
```

and don't forget to pump to go through with the tap

```
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
```

Have a look at the full code sample the flutter team is using to test dialogs: [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/material/dialog_test.dart)

Answer (score -1):

I think finding by Icons.close seems reasonable. I did similarly in my app. Another option could be assuming the x,y of the button in the navigation bar and just tapping at that location on the screen.

Answer (score -2):

I faced a similar problem earlier and I found the following solution that worked fine for my case.

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog')
```

Or you can write like,

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator.pop(context);
```

You can check the brief documentation on [Flutter Navigation and Routing](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation) here.

Hope, this would work. Have a great day.

Comment: Thanks, but contexts aren't available to tests. Tests are driven via WidgetTester.